# getting error while sending mail from glassfish server

Tags: java, email, glassfish

i have glass fish server i am trying to send mail through that server. but getting an error.

CODE as below

```
 import java.util.Properties; 
import javax.mail.*; 
import javax.mail.internet.*; 
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.Message;
 import javax.mail.MessagingException;
public class EmailService{ 

  public static void main(String[] args) { 

   String to="to@gmail.com";//change accordingly 
   String from="from@";//change accordingly 
   String password="password";//change accordingly 
   System.out.println("started");
   Properties props = new Properties(); 
   props.put("mail.smtps.host", "localhost"); 
   props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.port", "8080"); 
   props.put("mail.smtps.socketFactory.class", 
   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"); 
   props.put("mail.smtps.auth", "true"); 
   props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps"); 
   props.put("mail.smtps.connectiontimeout", "90000");
   props.put("mail.smtps.timeout", "90000");

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, 
   new javax.mail.Authenticator() { 
       protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() { 
     return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");
     } 
     }); 
    try { 
  System.out.println("started");
  MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session); 
  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from)); 
  message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress("to")); 
  message.setSubject("Nothing Special.."); 
  message.setText("Send Mail By Java Programmm...."); 
  System.out.println("started");
//send message 
 System.out.println(message);
 Transport.send(message); 
  System.out.println("started");
  System.out.println("message sent successfully"); 

  } catch (MessagingException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);} 

   } 
   }
```

But i am getting an error. i have changed the port details. created Javamail session is glassfishserver as well.

```
 javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage@6daa8eb7
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.MessagingExcep
 tion: Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: I guess you don't have a mailserver installed on `localhost`?

Comment: if i try to connect to SMTP.company.com also i am getting same error. if i am connecting from office network

Comment: check your mail client settings. You can use what you find there in your code